# jQuery Waterfall items not sitting in order of their HTML layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

Evening.

I am using jQuery Waterfall which is a pinterest style grid layout based of masonry i believe.

The issue i am having is that the items are not being displayed as i would hope.

Lets say the html markup is like this:

```
<div id="buildcontainer">

    <div class='blogresults'>ITEM 1</div>

    <div class='blogresults'>ITEM 2</div>

    <div class='blogresults'>ITEM 3</div>

    <div class='blogresults'>>ITEM 4</div>

</div>
```

When checking the source code, that is the mark up. Yet in my website grid the items are displayed such as:

```
ITEM 3 | ITEM 1 | ITEM 4 | ITEM 2
```

This wouldnt normally be a problem, except i am ordering the contents depending on their popularity. I could hack it and change the order of the content, but its all dynamically loaded.

Any help on this? Any options for Waterfall that i can use.

As an example here is my website:

SOLVED.

The order should be: KTM RC8 | BLACK FABIA VRS | YELLOW VRS | AUDI TT

Is this a case of my items css styling? Here is the styling for that:

```
.blogresults { 
border: 0px solid #fff;
background-color: #fff;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
z-index: 500;
disply: inline-block;
float:;
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 200ms;
 -moz-transition: box-shadow 200ms;
 -o-transition: box-shadow 200ms;
 -ms-transition: box-shadow 200ms;
 transition: box-shadow 200ms;
}

#buildcontainer {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Craig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

The issue was something do with me wrapping the items in an  tag. Moved the  tag into the .blogresults div and all works fine.